# Drupal 7 : Advanced theme settings after submission

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have a problem with advanced settings in theme-settings.php. i can build custom form with this -->

```
mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
 //custom form
}
```

function. But how i can integrate new function after settings submission? like this:

```
mytheme_system_theme_settings_submit_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  // if form submited -> execute function
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom submission handler to the form in the alter function itself:

```
function mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Build up the rest of the form.

  // Add your submission handler to the form.
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_submit';
}

function mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Form has been submitted, execute your function.
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get this error:
Call to undefined function mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_submit() in includes/form.inc on line 1460
Any ideas?

Comment: You need to replace `my_theme` with the name of your theme ;)

Comment: ha, I did that, just reformatted it back to what you had. Everywhere above that you have "mytheme" I have "cdf" so my error says: cdf_form_system_theme_settings_submit().

Comment: strange, so it works, as long as you don't have a managed_file field type, as soon as you have that, it doesn't work (and you get the above error). that's strange. Any ideas?